# How to make a RESTFUL PUT call angulajrs

Tags: json, angularjs, rest

Im confused on how to make a RESTFUL API call with 'PUT'. I'm basically trying to save an edited profile but I'm confused on how to make the API call for it. This is what I have so far ...

```
var edit = angular.module('edit', ['ui.bootstrap','ngResource'])
.factory('editable', function($resource) {

    return {

        // get JSON helper function
        getJSON : function(apicall) {

            if(sessionStorage["EditUserId"] == undefined) {
               // get the user id
                var userid = sessionStorage["cerestiuserid"]; 
            }
            else {
                var userid = sessionStorage["EditUserId"];
            }


            // json we get from server
            var apicall = sessionStorage["cerestihome"];   

            // new api
            return $resource(apicall + "/api/profiles/", {Userid:userid}, {'PUT': {method: 'Put'}});  
        }
    };
});
```

This is the controller ...

```
//editable object
var object = editable.getJSON();
var edit = new object();

edit.UserName = "Hello World";
edit.$save();
```

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: Take a look at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource . There is an example of custom PUT method on the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use restagular to invoke put service.

For example

```
   admin.factory('AdminService', ['Restangular', 'AppConstants', 'AdminRestangular', 'WorkFlowRestangular', 'localStorageService',
        function(Restangular, AppConstants, AdminRestangular, WorkFlowRestangular, localStorageService) {

    var service = {}

        service.updateAgency = function(data) {

                return AdminRestangular.all(AppConstants.serviceUrls.agency).doPUT(data);
            };

    return service 
}]);
```

Comment: Did you check this?,. Hope this is useful for you.

Comment: yes thank you. Easy question but why are you using a factory instead of a module? What's the difference between the two?